# Did the Kriegsmarine allow crewmen and sailors to own and bring aboard pets on their ships?

Tags: nazi-germany

My question is inspired by reading about the [Unsinkable Sam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsinkable_Sam) story, where according to Wikipedia the *Unsinkable Sam* was initially living aboard the German battleship [Bismarck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_battleship_Bismarck).

Now my question isn't whether or not the story of Unsinkable Sam is real or not, or whether there really was a cat aboard Bismark, but rather that I am simply wondering: Did the Kriegsmarine really allow crew to have pets on ships?

To summarize my question:

- Did the Kriegsmarine officially allow crew to have pets on board warships?
- If not, did crewmen still bring pets aboard ships as far historical evidence suggest and was it common?

Comment: https://connectingvets.radio.com/articles/bears-other-animals-kept-mascots-onboard-us-navy-ships On the US Navy...

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship%27s_cat Says the Royal Navy banned pets aboard vessels in 1975.

Comment: https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/animal-mascots-once-sailed-navy-180957508/ and so forth. Seems quite likely they were common in all navies in WWII.

Comment: @JonCuster True. I did in fact found confirmation about British navy allowing pets on ships during world war 2, But i am more curious about German navy. Because i couldn't find much reliable information about pets on German ships.

Comment: The german version of [Ship's cat - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship%27s_cat) ([Schiffskatze](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schiffskatze)) quotes the *Jahrbuch der deutschen kriegsmarine, 1936* (Yearbook of the german navy, 1936): **The Austro-Hungarian Navy had "official ship cats" whose keeping on board was covered by their own budget.** Otherwise, it seems, they came with the rats.

Comment: There is a difference between (ordinary) sailors being allowed to bring their pets and captains being allowed to organize a ship's pet/mascot. Your question should clarify if you are interested in one or both.

Comment: @o.m. well after a lot of googling i made sure that Krigsmarine didn't had an official or recognized concept of "ship's mascot" similar to western powers such as US or UK. So my question as stated is mostly about crew owning pets and bringing pets aboard.

Comment: Cats need not be pets.  You didn't want mice and rats to get into your stores.