# Was there an official order on ships' cats per vessel?

Tags: 20th-century, naval, animals

In the funny, but still (I assume) historically accurate material about "[The history of Ships Cats](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7HIY0GTEC8&list=TLPQMDMwMzIwMjE2B80ZR-tsYQ&index=2)", the author states that "many navies had standing order for minimum acceptable number of cats per vessel" (for purpose of combating rodents and to improve morale of the crew).

Does anyone know example of such order? Also, somehow related - who would be responsible for taking care of those felines - would it be just a kitchen hand doing something in spare time or was it a prestigious position held by an officer?

Just to narrow this  a little, lets focus on time from mid 19 to the mid 20 century and the broadly understood Western navies.

Comment: The German version of [Ship's cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship%27s_cat)  ([Schiffskatze](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schiffskatze#Dekrete,_Erlasse,_Vorschriften)) meantions that the Austrian-Hungarian navy had a official *ship cats* position with its own budget. (I believe this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find it)

Comment: @MarkJohnson - Cat's are insufferable normally. I can't imagine how snooty mine would get if he had an official position with the Austro-Hungarian Navy, and his own budget.

Comment: @T.E.D. This one seems to be enjoying itsself: [File:Pommern - Seaman enticing the ship's cat up on of the shrouds.jpg - Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pommern_-_Seaman_enticing_the_ship%27s_cat_up_on_of_the_shrouds.jpg#mw-jump-to-license). Mine probably wouldn't have a problem as long as she was always saluted properly by the Captian.

Comment: Related question [Did the Kriegsmarine allow crewmen and sailors to own and bring aboard pets on their ships?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/61405/16951).

Comment: @T.E.D. I'm sure that he would behave like a typical Austro-Hungarian general: aloof and full of disdain for those beneath him (read: everyone).